# Pyspark - How to concatenate columns of multiple dataframes into columns of one dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have multiple data frames (24 in total) with one column. I need to combine all of them to a single data frame. I created indexes and joined using indexes but it is quite slow to join all of them (All has same number of rows).

Please note that I'm using Pyspark 2.1

```
w = Window().orderBy(lit('A'))
df1 = df1.withColumn('Index',row_number().over(w))
df2 = df2.withColumn('Index',row_number().over(w))
joined_df = df1.join(df2,df1.Index=df2.Index,'Inner').drop(df2.Index)
df3 = df3.withColumn('Index',row_number().over(w))
joined_df = joined_df.join(df3,joined_df.Index=df3.Index).drop(df3.Index)
```

But as the joined_df grows, it keeps getting slower

DF1:

```
Col1
 2
 8
 18
 12
```

DF2:

```
Col2
 abc
 bcd
 def
 bbc
```

DF3:

```
Col3
 1.0
 2.2
 12.1
 1.9
```

Expected Results:

joined_df:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3
 2     abc   1.0
 8     bcd   2.2
 18    def   12.1
 12    bbc   1.9
```

Comment: You're doing it the correct way. Unfortunately without a primary key, spark is not suited for this type of operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You're doing it the correct way. Unfortunately without a primary key, spark is not suited for this type of operation.

---

Answer by [pault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858851/pault), pulled from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56009731/pyspark-how-to-concatenate-columns-of-multiple-dataframes-into-columns-of-one/56158000#comment98665007_56009731).